# How to implement mathematical expression from array value?

Tags: typescript, angular10

I have an array like below:

```js
var arrayFormula = [ {id:1, type:'Number', value: '5'}, {id:1, type:'Operator', value: '+'}, {id:1, type:'Number', value: '2'} ]
```

In typescript/angular I am expecting the value total = 5 + 2; total = 7;

Comment: Hi @Purushothaman c. Could include more of your code to show how you are calling this and viewing the output?

Comment: you need a switch case for `type` and the find the object that have the same id as operator `id` except those have `Operator` type and then do the calculation